# Multi Page form with Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form2

I want to create two different form. In the first form the users can enter the data.
Depending on the data given in the first step, i want to prepare some prefilled data in the second form.

It is possible to do so ?

Sorry for my English.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is totally possible.

Once the first form has been sent you validate and check the data. If your condition is met you'll store the data within the `session` and then redirect the user to the second form.

Once the second form has been validated correctly you can use the data from the `session` and the current forms data to do whatever you want to do.